# How do I filter out records that have a maximum value for a given range of records, with an index and a subindex (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

Say that I have the following table:

**Name|Age|Tel Number... etc | Index|SubIndex**

*Name|Age|Tel Number... etc* are the descriptive columns from which I'll need to extract information.
Index and SubIndex are the columns with which we will filter out the data.

*Index* and *SubIndex* are inputted in such a way that, Index can take values 8,9,10, but for each of these values, you can have the SubIndex as 1,2,3 etc.

So you can have the following:

*(Index,SubIndex)= (8,1);(8,2);(8,3);(9,1);(9,2);(10,1);(10,2);(10,3) etc*

I need to filter out records where, I get a range of records where Index is the Maximum Value to a Maximum Value - n, and for each of these I need the record where the SubIndex is the maximum value.

So with the above example, I might want the `Max(Index)` to `Max(Index-1)` with the `Max(SubIndex)`

So my output should be records which have (Index,SubIndex) as **(10,3); (9,2)**

I've figured out the simpler case of getting Maximum Value to a Maximum Value - n:

```
SELECT name, age FROM tablename
WHERE index BETWEEN
(SELECT MAX(index) FROM tablename) and (SELECT MAX(index)-1 FROM tablename)
```

However, it's the selection of the corresponding maximum SubIndex that I'm getting stuck. Any help is appreciated here, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, you can do it this way:

```
select t1.name, t1.age, t1.index, t1.subIndex
from tablename t1
     join (select index, subIndex
           from (select index, max(subIndex) as subIndex
                 from tablename 
                 group by index ) 
           where index between (select max(index)-1 from tablename) and (select max(index) from tablename)
          ) t2
     on (t1.index= t2.index and
         t1.subIndex= t2.subIndex)
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Use  `dense_rank()` for `Index` and `row_number()` for `SubIndex`

```
SELECT name, age 
FROM 
  (SELECT name, age,
      dense_rank() over(order by Index desc) dri,
      row_number() over(partition by index order by SubIndex desc) rnsub
   FROM tablename
  )
WHERE dri <=2 AND rnsub = 1
```